# Android - CursorAdapter-ish Subclass, for ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, cursor

I currently use a bunch of subclassed CursorAdapters with custom layouts throughout my app, populating them with a Cursor returned by an SQLite query, then allowing them to populate my ListView, after setting them with

```
setListAdapter(new SearchAdapter(this, searchCursor));
```

Is there anyway I can get the same behavior but instead of passing in a Cursor pass in an

```
ArrayList<String[]>
```

Would there be a different class to subclass? (Obviously) Or, should I convert the ArrayList to a Cursor somehow? Or, is there a different method I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with an array Adapter (also you can subclass Base adapter) and implement your own way of displaying objects in a list. there are plenty of tutorials on google on how to do that.

Just search ArrayAdapter, Base adapter. :D

Hope this helps,
Take care.

Comment: Would you happen to be able to point me in the direction of a tutorial that inflates a layout instead of using a class based one like this tutorial: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/custom-baseadapters/ ? I'd like to keep with the newView()/bindView() method ideaology of CursorAdapter if possible.

Comment: This did it: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html , thanks so much!

Comment: yeah the equivalent is using the view holder combined with the view tag. your second post is definitely what you need.